# Please check if I get and write the switch statement right?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Switch statement is also a conditional statement like if and else if statement but in more reliable way. The structure:

```
switch (conditional variable) {    
case condition 1:    
     conditional code    
     break;    
case condition 2:    
     conditional code    
     break;    
case condition 3:    
     conditional code    
     break;    
default:    
     conditional code
```

**real code:**

```
var baby = "crying"
switch (baby) {    
    case "sleeping":    
        alert ("Green light")    
        break;    
    case "playing":    
        alert ("Yellow light")    
        break;    
    case "crying":    
        alert ("Red light")    
        break;    
    default:    
        ("no lights")    
}
```

Comment: *"but in more reliable way"* – uhm, how so?

Comment: I think he meant "readable", even that not always

Comment: So the question is just "*Is this how to write `switch`*" ?

Comment: Well… does it work as you expect? Are you really looking for a http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: The default statement leads to nothing, you gotta check that.

Comment: @Gar you mean I should add alert?

Comment: @deceze Should I say fast ?    It didn't look reliable to me but to the person who taught me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the semicolon after alert and also alert missing on last statement :

```
var baby = "crying"
switch (baby) {    
case "sleeping":    
    alert ("Green light");   
    break;    
case "playing":    
    alert ("Yellow light");    
    break;    
case "crying":    
    alert ("Red light");   
    break;    
default:    
    alert ("no lights");    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter for client side script.

Comment: I didn't add semicolons because they aren't necessary.

Comment: @Waqas You should get used to including the semicolons, or you'll produce interesting bugs in some edge cases.